# g++: How to hide unwanted warning messages with -Wall

Tags: grep, g++

I'd like to compile my program with the -Wall switch but the library I am using generates ample warnings specific to an enum issue that I'd like to ignore:

tonkatruck.cpp:70:24: warning: enumeration value ‘Numpad9’ not handled in switch [-Wswitch]

I have tried to exclude the offending lines with:
g++ -c *.cpp -Wall | grep -v "Wswitch"

However, it has no effect on the output.
I'd appreciate if you could point out where my fault is.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
g++ -c *.cpp -Wall 2>1 | grep -v "Wswitch"
```

to direct stderr to stdout so that grep can process those warnings. you can also use:

```
g++ -c *.cpp -Wall -Wno-switch
```